# Don't see syslog get logged anywhere on server

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I want to export syslog from an IP phone to a remote syslog server.
I have set everything up, I can see the syslog packets getting to the server when doing a tcpdump, but I don't see the syslog in a logfile anywhere.
I assume those should get logged into /var/log/messages, but I don't see it in there.
What am I doing wrong?

Server is running:

```
# systemctl status rsyslog
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-06 18:44:04 EST; 1 weeks 1 days ago
 Main PID: 22533 (rsyslogd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
           └─22533 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

Here is /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###

# ss -anup
State      Recv-Q Send-Q              Local Address:Port                             Peer Address:Port
UNCONN     0      0                   192.168.122.1:53                                          *:*                   users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2450,fd=5))
UNCONN     0      0                        *%virbr0:67                                          *:*                   users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2450,fd=3))
UNCONN     0      0                       127.0.0.1:323                                         *:*                   users:(("chronyd",pid=798,fd=1))
UNCONN     0      0                               *:514                                         *:*                   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=2358,fd=3))
UNCONN     0      0                               *:5353                                        *:*                   users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=753,fd=12))
UNCONN     0      0                               *:48448                                       *:*                   users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=753,fd=13))
UNCONN     0      0                             ::1:323                                        :::*                   users:(("chronyd",pid=798,fd=2))
UNCONN     0      0                              :::514                                        :::*                   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=2358,fd=4))
```

Comment: Did you open the port in your firewall?

Comment: Server and client on are on the same network and iptables is allow all.

Comment: Restarted and added ss -anup output into my original question above.

Answer (score 0):

`Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-06 18:44:04 EST; 1 weeks 1 days ago`

How about restarting it?

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Check if listening for UDP:

```
ss -anup
```

Answer (score 0):

Change OmitLocalLogging to off:

$OmitLocalLogging off

This is a problem with reception via local log socket.